# Why can't I retrieve the price from a webpage?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait

I am trying to retrieve a price from a product on a webshop but can't find the right code to get it.

Price of product I want to extract: https://www.berger-camping.nl/zoeken/?q=3138522088064

This is the line of code I have to retrieve the price:

```
Prijs_BergerCamping = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//div[@class="prod_price__prod_price"]').text
        print(Prijs_BergerCamping)
```

Any tips on what I seem to be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct.
I guess all you missing is to wait for element visibility.
This code works:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = "https://www.berger-camping.nl/zoeken/?q=3138522088064"
driver.get(url)

price = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="prod_price__prod_price"]'))).text
print(price)
```

The output is:

```
79,99 €
```

But you also need to close the cookies banner and Select store dialog (at least I see it). So, my code has the following additionals:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = "https://www.berger-camping.nl/zoeken/?q=3138522088064"
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@style] //*[contains(@class,'uk-close')]"))).click()
price = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="prod_price__prod_price"]'))).text
print(price)
```

Comment: Yes thankyou! I think it is because first I check for a discounted price. If no discounted price is found, then I want to retrieve the price as mentioned above. I seems that if there is no discounted price, no element gets found and the 'normal' price doens't get retrieved..?

Comment: Yes i got that, thanks! What i want to have is: 1. look for a discounted price 2. if not found, get the base price 3. no product found at all, make note and continue with next iteration. Is that something i can do in a try catch?

Comment: This definitely possible, but this totally changes the question you initially asked here

Comment: You are correct, my apologies. Now that i am able to retrieve a 'base price' and (if available) a 'discounted' price, I want to have 3 options that have to be checked as i mentioned above. I think this is possible with a try catch?

Comment: Yes, this can be done with use of try - catch. Also even without try - catch block. But, again, this totally changes the question. So I think it will be better to close this question as resolved since I answered accordingly to what you asked and then to ask a new question where you should describe what exactly is the problem, sharing your current code trials and what exactly not worked there.